# How can I use "FindNext" in Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I want to find the word I chose using python and win32com. How do I use FindNext?

```
def test(path_file):
text = "1061"
# 새 창 열기
excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
# 파일 열기
excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(path_file)
excel.Worksheets(result_sheet).Select(True)
excel.Worksheets(result_sheet).Range("B1:B100").Find(text)
```